# In jquery dynatree , class for node is removed when I click on lazy node

Tags: dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I am using jquery-dynatree with context-menu option.

For one of the menu item on context-menu, I need to show the entire sub-tree as a selection.
i.e. selected node and all its children, I am able to do that using below code :

```
node.visit(function(childnode){
    $(childnode.span).addClass("copy");  // <== This works
});
```

Now I have 2 issues:

1) First issue is I have lazy node option, so whenever I click on menu-item, I need to show entire sub-tree as selected, for that I am using below code

```
node.visit(function(childnode){
    childnode.expand(true);  // <== This works
    $(childnode.span).addClass("copy"); // <== Does not work
});
```

but it does not work fully, it only expands the nodes upto level I have initialized and also after expansion it does not add required CSS class "copy" to itself or children nodes.

2) Second issue is , once I have manually expanded all the nodes and selected parent-node so that entire subtree is shown using class "copy" , now whenever I click on any parent lazy node to retrieve those children, the "copy" class is removed from those selected nodes

Looking forward to some tips on solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution now for 1st point, as I was trying to click on parent in collapsed mode, I had to first expand the node itself before expanding its children nodes.

```
 node.expand(true); // This line was missing, it made the things work
                node.visit(function(childnode){
                    childnode.expand(true);
                    $(childnode.span).addClass("copy");
                });
```